# How to add a editable hyperlink in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, backend

I have a WooCommerce shop and would like to add a function inside the backend of the page.

I added already inside the variable.php below the size variation dropdown one of the **size guide link**:

```
<a href="https://www.my-site.com/sizeguide-woman-product-a">Find the perfect size</a>
</div>
```

But how could I create a function that the link is editable in each product via the backend?

For Example, We have **Product A** with this size guide Link:

```
www.my-site.com/sizeguide-woman-product-a
```

And we have **Product B** with this Link:

```
www.my-site.com/sizeguide-men-product-b
```

I made research already, but for some reason, I didn't found anything. Maybe I am missing the right Keywords.

Comment: One option would be to use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and add a Field Group that matches "product" type posts and either provides an URL or a Post field. I assume the "sizeguide" are posts or pages themselves? This way you could select the appropriate post (page) and get the URL of the selected post `by get_permalink()`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, if I can't fix it with pure code, I may give this a try.